# Atividade estacionamento em JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso fazer um exercício de aula de um sistema de estacionamento, segue o formato em HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Estacionamento</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        fieldset { width:250px; }
        label { display:block; float:left; } 
        label, input, textarea, select { width:150px; margin: 5px 0; }
        th, td { border:1px solid #ccc; font-size:0.9em; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="formulario">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Estacionamento</legend>

            <label for="tempoPermanencia" >Informe o tempo de permanencia:</label>
            <input type="text" id="tempoPermanencia" name="tempoPermanencia" /><br /><br />

            <button type="button" id="button" onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button><br /><br />

            <label for="total" >Total a pagar:</label>
            <input type="text" id="total" name="total" readonly="readonly"/><br /><br />    

        </fieldset>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="estacionamento.js"></script>
</body>
```

As regras do estacionamento são:

3,00 a cada hora
30,00 diária

```
# A partir de 3hs 4,00 a cada 30 min

var array = [];

function calcular(){
    var tempoPermanencia = $("#tempoPermanencia").val();
    var totalAcumulado = 0;


var estacionamento = new Object();
estacionamento['tempoPermanencia'] = tempoPermanencia;
estacionamento['totalAcumulado'] = totalAcumulado;


array.push(estacionamento);

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

    var hora = $("#tempoPermanencia").val().split(":");


    if (array[i].tempoPermanencia >= "01:00"){

        if(hora[1] == "00"){
            totalAcumulado += 5 * hora[0];
        }
        else if(hora[1] != "00"){
            totalAcumulado += (5 * hora[0]) + 2.5;

            console.log(hora);

        }

    }else if (array[i].tempoPermanencia == "00:30"){

        totalAcumulado += 2.5;
    }
    else if (array[i].tempoPermanencia == "24:00"){

        totalAcumulado += 50;

    }
    else if (array[i].tempoPermanencia >= "03:00"){         

        if(hora[1] == "00"){ 
            totalAcumulado += (hora[0] * 2) * 2;

            console.log(hora);

        }else if(hora[1] != "00"){
            totalAcumulado += (hora[0] * 2 + 1) * 2;

            console.log(hora);

        }

    }
//$("#total").val(totalAcumulado);
//$("#tempoPermanencia").val("");
//$("#tempoPermanencia").focus();

}
$("#total").val(totalAcumulado);
$("#tempoPermanencia").val("");
$("#tempoPermanencia").focus(); 
}
```

Eu fiz dessa forma mas gostaria de verificar se existe uma forma mais eficiente, acredito que a minha esteja com erros também... Obrigada a todos

Comment: Vc "acredita que contém erros"? O professor não ensinou a verificar erros no console?

Comment: Erros no sentido de não estar 100% atendendo o que o exercício pede... Não está apresentando erro de sintaxe

Answer (score 1):

Achei sua lógica confusa, minha sugestão seria somar as horas com os minutos, e trabalhar apenas com os minutos. Então você poderia calcular o total dessa maneira:

```
var aPagar = 0;

// Se ficou mais que 5 horas e meia, paga o teto (diária = 1140 minutos)
while (minutos > 330) {
  aPagar += 30
  minutos -= 1140
}

// Se ficou mais que 3 horas, paga R$4 por 30 minutos 
while (minutos > 180) {
  aPagar += 4
  minutos -= 30
}

// Finalmente, cobra $3 por hora
while (minutos > 0) {
  aPagar += 3
  minutos -= 60
}
```